How is this question about resolution off-topic?
I have asked a question about Upschaling and Pixel Replication

I have frequently heard that it is better to have a display resolution
with the resolution of the content you want to display on the device.
I.e if your content is 720p it is going to look better in a device
with 720p than a 1080p or 4k/8k.
You have a 8k TV and you are seing 720p content. Since the pixel count
is 6 times vertically and 6 times horizontally the simplest thing to
do would be to multiply each pixel 6 times vertically and 6 times
horizontally. I don't know how a square of 36 pixels would look
compared to 1 big pixel even if they had the same color on two screens
with the same total size and 36 times the density in the higher
resolution screen viewed from the same distance.
I know that AI hallucinates and there can be mistakes/errors in
fidellity with replication and any upscale algorithm but it seems
strange to claim that a 720p video will look best at a 720p display
(all else equal) that on 8k display. I want to be able to see all
sorts of content on 1 single display instead of changing displays
depending on my content. I don't need to invent data and try to
increase the quality of the image when that data isn't there in the
first place
What is the difference between 1 pixel in 720p and the respective 36
pixel block in 8k (all else equal the only difference in the screens
is their resolution) created from integer scalling, especially without
assumming that the screens' pixels are distributed uniformly;
perfectly colinear, parallel, perpendicular and all coplanar and
equidistant without assuming that the screen is a perfect rectangle in
a single plane (instead of the simplifying assumption we have actual
screens as they are)?

I don't understand how it is outside of the scope of the tags video, resolution and tentatively even display.
My question is
Why is the specific question off-topic and outside of the scope of the tags?

You receive a lot of feedback. It seems the question was unclear. Now, the community could reopen the question and then close it because it is unclear, but it wouldn't change the fact that it is unclear. Have you improved the clarity of the question by editing it, not by submitting comments to clarify your question?

For instance, it's not clear the relevancy of this statement: "I know that AI hallucinates, and there can be mistakes/errors in fidelity with replication and any upscale algorithm, but it seems strange to claim that a 720p video will look best at a 720p display (all else equal) than on an 8k display." You recognize that AI can and likely did hallucinate when it gave you that response.

@Ramhound No AI gave me a responce. AI is used in image enhancement etc. I recognize simply that you can't invent new information the best AI can do is estimate (it can look ugly). Are you punishing me for an "irrrelevant" statement? There are three different close reasons. First people alleged it was opinion based so I tried to move away from how it looks different and focus on the factual differences (appearances vs reality). But then the question was closed as being off-topic. The comments I submitted was not to clarify my question but for me to understand what people thought about it.

Still doesn’t explain why you mention GenAI. What you say about GenAI does not seem to be anything of substance. I am not punishing anyone, closure votes, are not punishment. I also didn’t vote on this particular question, not that it would matter, since I agree the question needed to be closed and improved before it can be answered

@Ramhound  I never mentioned GenAI I mentioned AI because AI is used for image enhanment and I wanted to make myself clear that I don't want any enhancement. I don't want any detail that wasn't there. Why is it substantial for the question to understand the reason for the AI (not GenAI) mention? I removed the unfortunate mention of AI. So now if you can answer why the question is off-topic please we digress.

@Ramhound I received no feedback. I am trying to understand how the question isn't clear, on-topic and answerable based on evidence.

There are 18 comments to the original question. Suggesting you received no feedback isn't exactly a clear representation of the facts.  You actually did receive feedback on your question before it was closed.

@Ramhound I am probably the only person who can give feedback to himself...... 10 of these 18 are mine. Jsotola says it is unclear what is the question. Mokubai informs me of the name of the term (no feedback there), Then Jsotola tells me the question is Opinion Based. And the 5 comments from music2myear were an attempt to reinterpret myquestion (no I didn't mean source I really meant content) and a discussion about my person (about how ignorant I am of the source resolution) instead of my question. I received no feedback. Just 2 ultimata that the question was unclear/opinion based.

@Ramhound Let me quote Mokubai on a different question https://superuser.com/questions/1854428/design-nanoled-vs-microled-computer-screeens#comment2939106_1854428. Just because you say the question is unclear or opinion based doesn't make it so. My comment weren't an attempt to clarify the question but understand what issues others find with it (why is it unclear why is it opinion based). I editted the question more that a couple of times. I received no more feedback that 2 ultimata.

@GeorgeNtoulos I just left you a comment on the closed question post for an idea to help you fix it. Just need to reword it some to be more clear and concise and then you'll probably get votes to help you reopen it. This has happened to me a lot on the Politics SE community, so I keep learning each SE site that I visit and post on, best ways to learn, making mistakes..... choo choo, chugga chugga, choo choo!!

@JoepvanSteen Please post answers as answers (didn't you read on two screens with the same total size). I edited the question anyway.  Should I edit the META question accordingly?

@JoepvanSteen I am not asking for a suggestion on learning materials. I am not asking someone to suggest a textbook. A "problem" would be viewing content with different resolution on 1 single screen.

@JoepvanSteen And I am asking to have these physics explained.

@JoepvanSteen In a 720p screen (24" from 1 ft away) I can hardly make out 1 big individual pixel. I don't think from 1 ft away I could make out the individual subpixels in a 36 pixel block fron a 8k screen (24" from 1 ft away).

@JoepvanSteen Post answers as answers. Not all pixels are the same size. In order to fit 36 times the pixel count inside the same panel side each pixel is going to be 36 times smaller.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle  For me there is no Reopen button. This probably is a reputation-based privilage. My question is in the review queue.

@GeorgeNtoulos - If it’s in the queue all you can do is wait for the community to reopen your question. If the question is not reopened, then edit it again, and select the checkbox indicating your address the closure. Authors of questions don’t have the ability to vote to reopen a question only edit the question and select the checkbox. Trying to reopen a question that hasn’t been improved is a waste of the communities time and limited resources

@Ramhound There is nothing for me to learn (how to ask good questions, how to improve said question) when I am at the mercy of the community and good will.

If you think it’s a waste of time to improve the quality of your question, and there is nothing to learn (on how to ask high quality questions), then there isn’t much to say so I will disengage

@Ramhound I don't think it is a waste of time to improve the questions. I am saying that there is no rules on that. Especially when the "quality" is decided by arbitrary voting. I am saying I am not told how to improve the questions. I am happy to learn there is nothing to learn because of the opacity of the SE exchange rules and the arbitrariness of voting it's neither a refusal to learn nor a claim that "I know enough" it is a complain of the opacity and arbitrariness.

@GeorgeNtoulos - There absolutely are rules and guidelines but they are not explicit, more general guidelines since what is considered high quality is fairly subjective. I still feel I am going to disengage from this question at this point
